# show('slide') effect on repeat?

Tags: jquery, hover, slide

I have a hidden div which I would like to slide upwards on hover over on another div.

```
$('.gallery-single a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.gallery-single-title', this).show('slide', { direction: 'down' }, 1000);
    $('.black', this).css({ opacity: 0 });

});
```

Now when I hover over, the slide action happens on repeat for some reason, I would like to have it slide upwards only once. Would appreciate any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/cCTpd/2/

Comment: I'm confused.  You said you want it to slide up but your code has it sliding down.  Can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: lol I yes as funny as it sounds, slide down actually slides its up =S
please check the JSfiddle link attached now

Comment: I don't understand what you want it to do.  It slides up both when you enter and leave the item... that's just as you've programmed it.  I recommend `hover()` as provided below by **natedavisolds**.   Notice how he has it coded to slide up AND down.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with the hover event and changing the class.  I am assuming some of your html structure here. I could answer a bit better if I could see it.

```
$('.gallery-single a').hover(
    function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('slid')) {
            $(this).find('.gallery-single-title').slideUp(1000);
            $(this).find('.black').css({ opacity: 0 });
            $(this).addClass('slid');
        } 
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).find('.gallery-single-title').slideDown(1000);
        $(this).find('.black').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $(this).removeClass('slid');
    }
);
```

### Update

Here is the updated code to make it behave the way that you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/YJaM5/7/

There is only one change to the javascript above:

```
$(this).find('.black').animate({ opacity: .5 });
```

I also recommend setting the event to `$('.gallery-single')` just in case you ever want to have this effect without the link, but it isn't neccessary.

All the other changes are to the css

```
.gallery-single {
    display:inline-block; 
    margin: 12px; 
    background:#333;
    width: 300px; 
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}

.gallery-single img { border:none; }

.black {
    background-color:#000000;
    width:300px;
    height:200px; 
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.gallery-single-title {
    font-family: 'ContinuumLightRegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    width:290px;
    height:60px; 
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    color: white;
    background:#00b9e1;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

Let me explain a bit. `position:relative;` is necessary on `.gallery-single` to keep it all in a neat package.  It allows us to set the bottom property to the title element.

I added `opacity: 0.5;` to the `.black` element so we didn't have to use js.

For `.gallery-single-title` I removed the `margin-top` and set

```
bottom: 0;
left:0;
```

This will slide the title element up and down regardless of the slideUp or slideDown but it doesn't matter because we are achieving the correct effect.

This should work for you now.

Comment: Although this works, its not the sliding effect im looking for. This slides down from the top..  I want them to slide up from below and then slide back down on mouse out

Comment: @Ian:  Isn't that being a little nit-picky?  It works... you just have to flip it around to your liking.

Comment: @Nate: However I tried this and it doesnt work quite right. On hover over no .gallery-single-title div is shown.. only once mouse out the div is shown which it shouldnt do. Thanks for the attempt anyway, appreciate the help

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle. The problems are resolved with a few changes to CSS. I will fork your code and post a link to some code that behaves the way you want it. It will have to be tomorrow though; look for it then.